# Is it possible to fly near/over Mount Everest?

Tags: air-travel, mount-everest

There is already a question about [getting to the top of Mount Everest without hiking too far](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/is-there-a-way-to-get-to-the-top-of-mount-everest-without-hiking-too-far) but what I want is a little bit different. I am looking for a flight (regular or tourist ). I don't want to leave the plane/helicopter but just want to have a great view of the mountain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous such offers:

- [Buddha Air](http://www.buddhaair.com/everest-experience/)
- [See Nepal](http://www.see-nepal.com/mountain_flight.php)
- [Tenzingasian holidays](http://tenzingasianholidays.com/destinations/nepal/everest-helicopter-flight-with-tashi-tenzing.html)
- [Get Your
  Guide](http://www.getyourguide.com/kathmandu-l101/mount-everest-1-hour-scenic-flight-t17942/)
- [Explore Himalayas](http://www.explorehimalaya.com/nepal_helicopter_tour.php)

They all seem to start at Kathmandu, so you can probably shop around there.

Comment: Although I would highly doubt if a regular helicopter can give you a top view of the Everest http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100826150018AAGhAmo

Answer (score 7):

I used Buddha Air to see Mount Everest a couple years ago. I don't think the airline matters though, as they all leave from the same airport. It was a 50 minute flight.

I went to a travel agency in Kathmandu, and they booked my flight by phone. The flights are **very** early, because the sky is clearest then. My host drove me to the airport, although you could take a taxi.

They let people walk up to the cockpit one by one to snap a picture. It's a very tight fit in the plane though. You do get to see it from your window (it's on your left when approaching it, on your right after turning around). According to the Air Buddha website, you get within 20 miles.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is regular morning flights. The starting time might be change in winter and summer season.

There are four airline who provided this services : Buddha Air, Yeti Airlines, Simrik Air and Saurya Airlines.[You can read more in Nepflights](http://nepflights.com/mountain-flight-in-nepal)

The place is only the Tribhuwan Airport.

You can also see the video here : [Video](http://vimeo.com/35859159)

Answer (score 1):

now days you will get a lots of option for Mt Everest Helicopter tour and on top of that you will get a group joining options which is quite cheap and if you search online you will find lots of tour operator who runs this kind of tours,